# NGINX proxy_pass 404 for assets

Tags: docker, nginx, http-status-code-404, assets

I have a problem with `proxy_pass` usage in config of nginx.

What I have is a docker container frontend and in nginx I am using proxy_pass to display this container when I access localhost/frontend/.

Everything works except all assets - when accessing localhost/frontend, images are loading from localhost/images instead of localhost/frontend/images. The same goes for js and css files.

Unfortunately, changing code of frontend container is not an option for me. Is there a solution how to redirect all these files to same location?

```
location /frontend/ {
        proxy_pass "http://frontend:3890/";
    }
```

Tried using this:

```
location /frontend/ {
        proxy_pass "http://frontend:3890/frontend/";
    }
```

but it did not help